# Gradle Wrapper to wrap runtime args in build invocation

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

Currently we have an app that builds with Gradle 2.3 (that uses the [ShadowJar plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) to build self-contained "fat JARS") that builds with the following build invocation:

```
gradle clean build shadowJar
```

This produces a fat JAR under `build/distributions`.

To actually run the app, there are a *ton* of runtime arguments, for example:

```
java -jar build/distributions/myapp.jar -Dfizz=true -Dbuzz=false -Dfoo=1 -Dbar=yes -Dgizmo=405
```

In reality there are dozens of other args. These runtime args are environment specific and are different on each machine this app runs on, and hence they can't be hardcoded somewhere inside the `build.gradle` file. Someone mentioned to me that it would be possible to use the Grails Wrapper to abstract these runtime args, so that perhaps I could just run `./gradlew run` and have that configured to do the same thing as the `java -jar` command above.

If this is true, what would this setup look like? If it's not true, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should have a folder called ini, where you would have ini files, like

> android.ini

In each .ini file you would define the values and you should create a loader which would determine what ini needs to be used, would load the file, parse its content and store them into settings variables.

Comment: Thanks @Lajos Arpad (+1) - where would this INI be located? What documentation do you see that suggests the existence of these INIs?

Comment: This is a common practice. I have created several projects using ini files and I was always satisfied with the results. Now, if your application should have different use-cases depending on the device, then you might need more ini files for several groups of devices and determine the device type in a loader, which will subsequently load the correct ini file. This is very useful, as ini file setting changes will not need source-code changes, even a tester can make the changes, so you, as a programmer will not be interested by the exact values, only with the approach.

Comment: Thanks again @Lasjos Arpad (+1) but I think you're confused - this isn't an Android or Mobile device.  This is just a Java application using Gradle to build it, which has no dependency on INI files, nor does it recommend to use them as any sort of a "best practice". The issue at hand is: can I use `gradlew` to wrap runtime args, and if so, how (specifically). If you can supply a solution that involves INI files, I'd consider it of course, but I'd need to see the whole solution, otherwise I think we're talking about 2 different things. Thanks again.

Comment: Why don't you put your values, like -Dfizz=true into an .ini file? If all the values are there and you load the values from the ini file, then, as a result, you will have your values and your only task will be to make sure your ini was read. You will not have to make sure that the runtime arguments are passed. After you have read the values from the ini file, you are able to initialize your settings. My proposal is to use an ini file and put there the arguments instead of always typing them. Also, you can have a setup application to have a user-friendly way to modify the ini